# How do I get rid of right margin in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

In react I am trying to display three elements below topElement. I want the 3 elements to fill up the space equally below topElement, ie get rid of the right hand gap circled in red in the image below (keep the gap at the top). To get to that point I have:

```
<Box padding={4}>
  <Grid container spacing={4}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
          <topElement />
      </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid container spacing={PADDING} direction="row" xs={12} 
      justify="space-between"  alignItems="center" >
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <el1...
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <El2...
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <El3...
        />
      </Grid>
...
```

So what is the final piece? TIA!

[image]

Comment: These components seem to all be custom, I'd suggest including the styling/components associated

Comment: Thanks, they are custom but quite complex. Nothing seems obviously to affect margins in them but I am v new to react so might be wrong.

Comment: If it's a framework, you can probably post that info too

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s material ui

Comment: In package.lock there are indeed refs to material-ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second Grid Container has an additional prop `xs={12}` set, which adds a `max-width: 100%` that affects your grid layout.

Remove that property from your grid container and it will work as expected.

Comment: I am sure I tried that hah ha! Thanks so much!!